# echo queries psql from a file as they are run

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a bash script that opens a file and executes a bunch of psql queries.

I want these queries to be echoed/print as and when they run.

How do I do the same ?
I have tried using \echo for inserts & inside stored procedures too, but it doesn't seem to work. How do I do it ?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work"? What happens, exactly? Please show the script, or at minimum the relevant parts that invoke `psql`.

Answer (score 14):

Use `psql --echo-all`.

```
$ psql --echo-all -c "SELECT 1;"
SELECT 1;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way that I know, that you can echo anything during the execution of a PostgreSQL function (named stored procedure), is with **raise**. This command is used to trown exceptions, but you can throw a NOTICE level exception, that will not interfere on the function execution. 
Maybe it is not exactly what you want, but is a good workaround. The way that PostgreSQL execute their procedures, don't allow runtime echos (like Sybase ou Ms SQL Server). See this examples (It will only work inside functions):

```
raise notice 'Some message';
```

It will output:

```
NOTICE:  Some message
```

Or passing vars to the debug:

```
raise notice 'Inserting '%' in '%'.',var_value,var_table;
```

When var_table = 'customers' and var_value = 'Joe Doe', it will output:

```
NOTICE:   Inserting 'Joe Doe' in 'customers'
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the raise notice statement but  I was looking for echoing out each line of sql statement  as and when executed

Comment: Ok. Can you provide more information? How the bash script act on the script that is in the file? It executes each one on a psql? Or just execute the whole file as a sql script?

In the fist case, you can execute a date command (bash) before each execution. In the second case, you can make a `select now();` before each sql command with the `psql -a` option.

Answer (score 1):

**--echo-queries**  (for shell script)

PGPASS='passwd'

su -c "PGPASSWORD=${PGPASS} psql -d postgres **--echo-queries** -qc "\pset border 2;" -c "show data_directory;"" postgres

Answer (score 0):

From the Postgres documentation [page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-psql.html) ( please note that the syntax of psql has remained largely unchanged over versions ), it is clearer with an example of a DDL.

There are several ways to echo. -e to echo just the queries only.

```
$ psql -ec "create table t1 ( c1 int ) " ;
create table t1 ( c1 int ) 
CREATE TABLE
```

If you do not want the "CREATE TABLE" message add a "-q" flag as well

```
$ psql -eqc "create table t1 ( c1 int ) " ;
create table t1 ( c1 int )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add header and footer to your script file:

```
\set origin_ECHO :ECHO

\set ECHO all

--****** YOUR SCRIPT TEXT *****

--.........

--*****************************

\set ECHO :origin_ECHO
```